# Default namespace in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know which is the default namespace of class defined by the programmer,if not specify any?

Let, take the case of Java.
In Java, if Programmer is not specify any package then default package is the java.lang

Same way i want to know about default namespace of C# classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`global` is the default namespace.

Example:

```
class GlobalClass {
}

namespace MyNamespace {
    class NameSpaceClass {
        public NameSpaceClass() {
            var globalObj = new global::GlobalClass();
        }
    }
}
```

MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx